# Problem Writing Image file in Python with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a small Python script using the PIL module to change the size of some textures used on a 3D Model in MultiGen Creator. I'm also using the openflight API so that's what the mg* functions are.

Here's the script

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

db = mgGetCurrentDb()
ret,index,name = mgGetFirstTexture (db)
while (ret):
 myAttr = mgReadImageAttributes (name)
 existingattrs = mgGetAttList (myAttr,fltImgHeight,fltImgWidth)
 print existingattrs[2]
 print existingattrs[4]
 if existingattrs[2] != 0 and existingattrs[4] != 0:
  Height = existingattrs[2]/4
  Width = existingattrs[4]/4

  print name
  print Width
  print Height
  imageFile = (name)
  im1 = Image.open(imageFile)
  im2 = im1.resize((Width,Height),PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
  ImgOut = "C:\DB\PLW\out.jpg"

  im2.save(ImgOut)

  ret,index,name = mgGetNextTexture (db)
```

Anyway all seems to work but when I try and write the file I get  the following error

```
E: Traceback (most recent call last):
E:   File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
E:   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1439, in save
E:     save_handler(self, fp, filename)
E:   File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
E:     ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
E:   File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 499, in _save
E:     s = e.encode_to_file(fh, bufsize)
E: IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  When you edit your question, read the code formatting guidelines on the right side of the page.

Comment: Is it as simple as changing this`ImgOut = "C:\DB\PLW\out.jpg"` to this `ImgOut = r"C:\DB\PLW\out.jpg"? I can't remember if python on Windows does backslashes properly if the escaped characters are not escapable.

Comment: On a separate note, Python convention is to lowercase variables and UpperCase classes.

Comment: john: what's the format of the image that you're openening it seems to me like you have a encoding problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to double up the `\` characters in your file name or use a raw string:

```
  ImgOut = "C:\\DB\\PLW\\out.jpg" 
  ImgOut = r"C:\DB\PLW\out.jpg"
```

The error message is basically saying it couldn't open the file.